# Azure orchestrator function issue when call sub orchestrator function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using a series of orchestrator functions. This means I am calling the sub-orchestrator function from the main. For example, I have orchestrator1, orchestrator2, and so on.

from orchestrator1 I am calling orchestrator2 and orchestrator3 with await. Here, there are 2 problems.

1. Await is not working properly.
2. When I call the sub-orchestrator function, it starts the main function again.

Could anyone face the same issues? Could you please let me know any solution to prevent these issues?

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(GetData))]
            public static async Task GetData(
                [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
                ILogger log)
            {
    .......
    var id = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<string>(GetID, data);
    .......

var name = await context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<string>(GetName, id);
    }
```

So here when GetID function is called, it will automatically start GetData function again. Also, it' not stay for await completion.

Comment: It will bey very hard to help without information. As a minimum please post the code of the function. Also, *Await is not working properly.* does not tell us anything.

Comment: @PeterBons - I have added an example code in the description.

Comment: look into using Activity functions instead of a sub-orchestration. Looks like it's the right approach for your use case. I don't exactly remember how durable orchestration works with sub-orchestrations, but, as the name states, they're 'durable' - they remember the state, which means they will look like they're starting over and over again, but the actual functions execute only once (unless told otherwise). You should get familiar with the hello world app first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio

Comment: @DuckLing - I have to do another sub-orchestration function from that sub Orchestration. And then I want to call the activity function. So what is the right approach for that?

Comment: if you really need a sub-orchestration, that's ok. a sub-orchestration is just like any other orchestration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1):

This is an Azure durable function feature. So when you call the sub-orchestrator functions, it will call that function and then return to the primary function's first line and start executing those lines again. Here, one thing is that it will not execute the sub-orchestrator function again but it fills the return value. Also, it will execute other functions as well after this executed function.

The property context.IsReplaying is returning the true value until the executed function. After that, it will return false.